# SQL Server Import Data w/o Linked Server/Import

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a way to import data from an Excel or csv file into a SQL Server table without using linked server/BULK INSERT/OPENROWSET etc & import utility?

I am looking more for SQL query that will do that for me.

I can use the import utility, but I am looking to have this in a script instead. Anyone has the T-SQL for it?

Comment: BULK INSERT and OPENROWSET are already T-SQL. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/import-bulk-data-by-using-bulk-insert-or-openrowset-bulk-sql-server Just write the script.

Comment: SSIS will do this very simply; create the source connections for your excel/csv files then create the ODBC connections for your destination table(s). Map the columns and you should be good to go unless I am missing something in your question.

Comment: any example to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Bro Try this. it will helpfull and increase your scope of R&D.

```
-- One-time exec--------

EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;  
GO  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO  
EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1;  
GO  
ECONFIGURE;  
GO  
--------------------------

--Query Command
EXEC master.dbo.xp_cmdshell 'type D:\Excel_test.txt'
```

by using this you are able to read the text file, XML file, etc, office file is not read correctly, So, need more R&D.
It is doable, you everything possible in coding.
You can also study about Filegroup in Mssql.

I hope it will help you and mark me if you like.

Comment: This does not work... Msg 15247, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_configure, Line 105 [Batch Start Line 0]
User does not have permission to perform this action.

Comment: first execute it,     EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;  
GO  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO  
EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1;  
GO  
ECONFIGURE;  
GO

Answer (score 0):

You have all kinds of options available to you for something like this.  Of course you can move the data both ways.

Export Data to Excel file
Create an Excel file named testing having the headers same as that of SQLServerTable columns
Here is Query:
Excel 2003 (.Xls) file:

```
insert into OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 'Excel 8.0;Database=D:\testing.xls;', 'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]') select * from SQLServerTable
```

Excel 2007 (.Xlsx) file:

```
insert into OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 'Excel 12.0;Database=D:\testing.xlsx;', 'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]') select * from SQLServerTable
```

Import data from Excel to new SQL Server table
Excel 2003 (.Xls) file:

```
select * into SQLServerTable FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 'Excel 8.0;Database=D:\testing.xls;HDR=YES', 'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]')
```

Excel 2007 (.Xlsx) file:

```
Select * into SQLServerTable FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 'Excel 12.0;Database=D:\testing.xlsx;HDR=YES', 'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]')
```

Import data from Excel to existing SQL Server table
Excel 2003 (.Xls) file:

```
Insert into SQLServerTable Select * FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 'Excel 8.0;Database=D:\testing.xls;HDR=YES', 'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]')
```

Excel 2007 (.Xlsx) file:

```
INSERT INTO SQLServerTable select * FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 'Excel 12.0;Database=D:\testing.xlsx;HDR=YES', 'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]')
```

You could use VBA to do the work equally easily.

https://www.excel-sql-server.com/excel-sql-server-import-export-using-vba.htm#Excel%20Data%20Export%20to%20SQL%20Server%20Test%20Code